# Rules for barewords

Tags: raku

Barewords can be used at the left hand side of [Pair](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pair) declarations (this is not documented yet, I'm addressing [this issue right now](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2520), but I want to get everything right). However, I have not found what is and what's not going to be considered a bareword key anywhere.

This seems to work

```perl6
say (foo'bar-baz => 3); # OUTPUT: «foo'bar-baz => 3␤»
```

This does not

```perl6
say (foo-3 => 3); # OUTPUT: «(exit code 1) ===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /tmp/jorTNuKH9V␤Undeclared routine:␤    foo used at line 1␤␤»
```

So it apparently follows [the same syntax as the ordinary identifiers](https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Ordinary_identifiers). Is that correct? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no barewords in Perl 6 in the sense that they exist in Perl 5, and the term isn't used in Perl 6 at all.

There are two cases that we might call a "bare identifier":

1. An identifier immediately followed by zero or more horizontal whitespace characters (`\h*`), followed by the characters `=>`. This takes the identifier on the left as a pair key, and the term parsed after the `=>` as a pair value. This is an entirely syntactic decision; the existence of, for example, a sub or type with that identifier will not have any influence.
2. An identifier followed by whitespace (or some other statement separator or terminator). If there is already a type of that name, then it is compiled into a reference to the type object. Otherwise, it will always be taken as a sub call. If no sub declaration of that name exists yet, it will be considered a call to a post-declared sub, and an error produced at CHECK-time if a sub with that name isn't later declared.

These two cases are only related in the sense that they are both cases of `term`s in the Perl 6 grammar, and that they both look to parse an `identifier`, which follow [the standard rules linked in the question](https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Ordinary_identifiers). Which wins is determined by Longest Token Matching semantics; the restriction that there may only be horizontal whitespace between the identifier and `=>` exists to make sure that the identifier, whitespace, and `=>` will together be counted as the declarative prefix, and so case 1 will always win over case 2.

Comment: Would "identifier-like literal" be a better term for that?

Comment: I took "bare identifier" from the S02 design docs. It's possible that "auto-quoted identifier" might be suitable, but that may diminish an important difference: pair forms that don't place the key in a quoting construct will be named parameters in the context of an argument list, while those with quotes will not be. So perhaps it's the whole construction - a fatarrow pair being one with a literal identifier to the left of the arrow - that we want to focus on.