# Which 'Perl Traps' have not been fixed in Raku?

Tags: raku

I was very pleased to find a link to a section called ["Perl Traps"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap#Perl-Traps) in the `perldocs`. It represents a refreshing sense of honesty in an increasingly tech-hyped world.

The https://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap#Perl-Traps link has 9 bullet points. My question is simple--now that it is 2024--which 'Perl Traps' have **not** been fixed in Raku?

I feel both Perl users and Raku users want a single SO Question to address all 9 bullets, not 9 SO Questions to address each one individually. Even a scorecard and/or fraction (e.g. `7/9`, `8/9`, `9/9` would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: The https://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap#Perl-Traps link has 9 bullet points. Perl users and Raku users want a ___single___ SO Question to address all 9 bullets, not 9 SO Questions to address each one individually. Even a scorecard and/or fraction (e.g. `7/9`, `8/9`, `9/9` would be useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting this as a community answer because I'm pretty sure it is far from complete.

---

---

> *Remember that many operations behave differently in a list context than they do in a scalar one. … .*

"Quoting" a couple comments from the reddit thread ["When [Raku] was being designed, what alternatives to expanding context sensitivity were considered?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/5lqhbr/when_perl_6_was_being_designed_what_alternatives/):

- "[Raku] has nothing like Perl context-sensitivity. Operators don't do different things depending on the surrounding context, and there is no `wantarray`. … ."  [｢1｣](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/5lqhbr/comment/dby4kam/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) .
- "The sort of context sensitivity that sucked in Perl, eg `wantarray`, was eliminated in Raku. The sort of context sensitivity that was already nice in Perl is even nicer in Raku. … ."  [｢2｣](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/5lqhbr/comment/dbyq9dh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) .

The latter comment was written by me; for more info about the nicer things see [the user doc page about contexts in Raku](https://docs.raku.org/language/contexts).

---

> *Avoid barewords if you can, especially all lowercase ones. You can't tell by just looking at it whether a bareword is a function or a string.*

"Quoting" the accepted answer of [SO "Rules for barewords"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977575/rules-for-barewords):

- "There are no barewords in [Raku] in the sense that they exist in Perl, and the term isn't used in [Raku] at all.
  (¶) There are two cases that we might call a "bare identifier": …  [｢3｣](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53978464/7270649) .

(Read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53978464/7270649) for details of the two "bare identifier" cases).

---

> *You cannot discern from mere inspection which builtins are unary operators (like `chop()` and `chdir()`) and which are list operators (like `print()` and `unlink()`).*

All routines can be programmatically inspected via `.signature`, `.arity`, etc.

Tools can use that to provide relevant human visual inspection ability too.

---

> *(Unless prototyped, user-defined subroutines can only be list operators, never unary ones.)*

All routines in Raku have signatures (which are Raku's vastly improved take on Perl's deeply problematic "prototypes").

---

> *People have a hard time remembering that some functions default to `$_`, `@ARGV`, or whatever, but that others which you might expect to do not.*

The main replacement for the idea of having to remember a list was to make method invocation without an explicit invocant work for any subroutine or method:

```
.&say # passes `$_` as the first argument to a `say` subroutine
.say  # passes `$_` as the first argument to a `say` method
```

One does still have to remember a list, but it's tiny and simple: the matchers (`m//` and cousins such as `s///` and `tr///`) default to operating on `$_`.

---

> *The `<FH>` construct is not the name of the filehandle, it is a readline operation on that handle. The data read is assigned to `$_` only if the file read is the sole condition in a while loop*

Raku's syntax related to file handle usage is conventional, like mainstream PLs.

---

> *Remember not to use `=` when you need `=~`; these two constructs are quite different: `$x =  /foo/;`, `$x =~ /foo/;`*

Raku replaced `=~` with `~~` (a.k.a. 'smart-match', which--despite its seemingly symmetric appearance--acts asymetrically in Raku).

---

> *The `do {}` construct isn't a real loop that you can use loop control on.*

Raku produces suitable error messages if a user attempts to use loop controls where they're not valid.

---

> *Use `my()` for local variables whenever you can get away with it (but see perlform for where you can't).*

In Raku to clarify scope you're required to use `my` or `our` in the first instance of a variable declaration  [｢4｣](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-declaring_a_list_of_variables) .  Otherwise, Raku pushed 'formats' outside the core language, so Raku doesn't have this Perl anomaly.

---

> *Using `local()` actually gives a local value to a global variable, which leaves you open to unforeseen side-effects of dynamic scoping.*

Raku doesn't have `local()` (or globals per se).

---

> *If you localize an exported variable in a module, its exported value will not change. The local name becomes an alias to a new value but the external name is still an alias for the original.*

???